# How to access (mount) the local hard drive and create a file in the %pre module of the Kickstart script？

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel

I want to access (mount) the local hard drive and create a file in the %pre module of the Kickstart script. But it doesn't seem to work. Please help me, thanks! The ks.cfg code is like this:

```
%pre
#!/bin/bash
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
touch /mnt/123456
mkdir /mnt/dir123456
umount /mnt
reboot
%end
```

Comment: Cross-posted to https://serverfault.com/questions/1105900/how-to-access-mount-the-local-hard-drive-and-create-a-file-in-the-pre-module

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is not a helpful statement. Does the disk get mounted, do any of the files get created? Why would you want to reboot during the pre-install script anyway? This will ensure your installation is never completed.